# It throws #2025 error when moving a image in as3/flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

When i tried to run the code, it throws an error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.controls::Image@a9030b1 to mx.containers.Canvas.

When i just try to replace

```
var num1:int = Canvas(event.currentTarget).mouseX;
```

with

```
var num1:int = Image(event.currentTarget).mouseX;
```

it throws below error:

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

Below is the code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="carcan();">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

            import mx.containers.Canvas;
            import mx.controls.Image;

            private var images:Array;
            private var dragInitiator:Image = new Image();
            private const IMAGE_COUNT:uint = 5;
            private var img:Image;


            private var dragInitiator:Image = new Image();

            private var points:flash.geom.Point;
            private var offset_x:int;
            private var offset_y:int;
            private var canal:Canvas;
            private var doDrag:Boolean;

            [Embed(source='cards/2C.png')]
            private var Image0:Class;

            [Embed(source='cards/2D.png')]
            private var Image1:Class;

            [Embed(source='cards/2H.png')]
            private var Image2:Class;

            [Embed(source='cards/2S.png')]
            private var Image3:Class;

            [Embed(source='cards/3C.png')]
             private var Image4:Class;

             public function carcan():void
             {
                canal = new Canvas();
                canal.setStyle("backgroundColor","blue");
                canal.x=100;
                canal.y=50;
                canal.width=500;
                canal.height=400;
                this.addChild(canal);
                init();
             }

             public function init():void
             {
              images = new Array(IMAGE_COUNT);

                 for (var i:int = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
                    {
                         img= new Image();
                            images[i] = this["Image" + i];
                            trace(images[i]);

                    img.x=(i*30)+50;
                    img.source=images[i];
                    img.id="Image"+i;
                    canal.addChild(img);

                     img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, md);
                    img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mm);
                    img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mu); 

                    }

             }

                public function md(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                img = new Image();
                doDrag=true;

                canal.setChildIndex(Image(event.target), images.length-1);
                img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mm);


            }
            public function mm(event:MouseEvent):void
            {


                 if(doDrag==true)
                 {
                    points = new Point();
                images = new Array(IMAGE_COUNT);


                img = new Image();
                img = Image(event.target);

                points.x=event.target.x;
                points.y=event.target.y;
                points = localToGlobal(points);
                img.x=points.x;
                img.y=points.y;


                var boundar:flash.geom.Rectangle=new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, this.width/ 2 + 3 * offset_x, this.height / 2 + 3 * offset_x);
                img.startDrag(false, boundar);
                 }
            }

            public function onmove(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                img = new Image();

            }

            public function mu(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                canal = new Canvas();
                canal.stopDrag();
                doDrag=false;



                this.stopDrag();
                doDrag=false;
                var num1:int = Canvas(event.currentTarget).mouseX;

        if(num1 > 50 && num1 < 80){
             canal.setChildIndex(dragInitiator, 0);
             setCards();                
            }
        if(num1 > 80 && num1 < 110){
             canal.setChildIndex(dragInitiator, 1);
            setCards(); 
            }
        if(num1 > 110 && num1 < 140){
             canal.setChildIndex(dragInitiator, 2);
            setCards(); 
            }
        if(num1 > 140 && num1 < 170){
             canal.setChildIndex(dragInitiator, 3);
            setCards(); 
            }
        if(num1 > 170 && num1 < 200){
            canal.setChildIndex(dragInitiator, 3);
            setCards(); 
            }


            }

             private function setCards():void{
            var b:int = 0;
            var a:int;
            var cardsArray:Array = this.getChildren();
            for(a = 0;a < cardsArray.length; a++)
            {
                canal.getChildAt(a).x = 90+b;
                b=b+20;
            }
             }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>    
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: That's some mix of code. Most likely you have your "dragInitiator" uninitialized when you call setChildIndex(). Also, why all those `img = new Image();` calls everywhere? It's plain ridiculous IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, just missed that line of draginitiator initialization. I have edited the code. The error is been pointing at num1:int=Canvas(event.currentTarget).mouseX;

Comment: This means your "event.currentTarget" is not type Canvas. What did you expect to receive as current target? Also, getting local coordinates is better done through MouseEvent object, there are "localX" and "localY" properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of casting Image as a CAnvas (the first error), you need to cast it... as an Image.

```
import spark.components.Image;

public function mu(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var current:Image = event.currentTarget as Image; //this is the correct way to cast event.currentTarget
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two error originate from different statements:
`#1034` originates from 
`var num1:int = Canvas(event.currentTarget).mouseX;`
because an `img` is not a Canvas

Where `#2025` originates from one of the 
`canal.setChildIndex(dragInitiator, ...);`
because `img` is not a child of canal, you have to `addChild(...)` before you can `setChildIndex(...)`

you can use `addChildAt` instead of `setChildIndex` it would work the same, if not a bit less efficiently.